# .Random.seed set incorrectly when knitr and DT::datatable() are used

Tags: r, knitr

Here is a simple R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
DT::datatable(iris)
runif(1)
```
````

When it knits, I get the following warning:

```
Warning in runif(1): '.Random.seed' is not an integer vector but of type 'NULL', so ignored
```

The same occurs for any call to a pseudo-random number generator, or with a call to `set.seed()`, provided a call to `DT::datatable()` precedes it.

If I insert `rm(.Random.seed)` after the call to datatable and before `runif(1)`, then there is no warning.

The warning does not occur when the two commands in the above code chunk are run in a regular R session.

Would this be an issue with package **knitr**, package **DT**, or base R?  (I want to know where to file it.)

Comment: I can reproduce this on my machine (Windows with pretty standard R installation). I would guess it's linked to the `DT` package as I haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: Yes this seems to be an issue with `DT`. If you put `rm(.Random.seed)` after `DT::datatable(iris)`, the warning should disappear. Might be a good idea to open an issue on `DT`'s [GitHub site](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/).

Comment: Thanks:  I have opened an Issue with DT:  [https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/463](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/463)

Answer (score 1):

The issue exists in the version of DT on CRAN, but not in the current development version.  See https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/463#issuecomment-339985427.  I can confirm that after

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")
```

the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!